# Load large images into Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, jpeg, image

I'm trying to make a basic application that displays an image from the camera, but I when I try to load the .jpg in from the sdcard with `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`, it returns null.

It doesn't give an out of memory error which I find strange, but the exact same code works fine on smaller images.

How does the generic gallery display huge pictures from the camera with so little memory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to set the inSampleSize as shown in [this example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-display-jpg-in-sdcard-on.html).

Comment: You could even try to dynamically choose `inSampleSize` by first using `inJustDecodeBounds` and comparing it to your available space.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this amazing tutorial

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

Well after working a lot i found out that the problem was not with code but the ram size of emulator, editing avd and increasing ram size solves all problems and saves huges pics easily. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that uses inSampleSize and dynamically determines the image resolution to use based on available memory:

http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/handling-large-images-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

send:

```
                        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
                    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o); 

                    int REQUIRED_SIZE = 640; 
                    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight; 
                    int scale = 1; 
                    while(true) { 
                        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE) break; 
                        width_tmp /= 2; 
                        height_tmp /= 2; 
                        scale *= 2; 
                    } 

                    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
                    o2.inSampleSize = scale; 
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2); 

                    ByteArrayOutputStream bs2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bs2);
                    getIntent().putExtra("byte_picture", bs2.toByteArray());
```

recive:

```
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data.getByteArrayExtra("byte_picture"),0,data.getByteArrayExtra("byte_picture").length);
```