# Loading big image to bitmap in android

Tags: android, image

Hi i am using below code to load images from sdcard, it is running correctly,

```
Bitmap picture=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard...");
```

or

```
Bitmap picture= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte[]..);
```

The `byte[]` array contains bytes read from sdcard by using `FileInputstream` and is not null. Both of above codes work fine. The problem is that they dont work for images that are larger e.g. i have an image of 1.8 mb in size. My app crashes while decoding the image. Any method used for larges image fails.
Any solution plz thakns.

Comment: resize the image and then use it.

Comment: what can be cause of it so that it may be solved because i need to use original image.

Comment: Because of size of heap in android, and your bitmap allocate the memory in the heap.

Comment: now i have debug it and when debuger reaches at the command mentioned above it halts and says that source is missing.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798756/load-large-images-into-bitmap

Answer (score 6):

Try to create purgeable Bitmap.

```
   byte[] data = ...(read byte array from file)
   BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   opt.inPurgeable = true;
   Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code to resize the image any size you need..

```
 Bitmap picture=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard...");
    int width = picture.getWidth();
    int height = picture.getWidth();
    float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    int newWidth = 70;
    int newHeight = (int) (70 / aspectRatio);       
    picture= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(picture, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

Comment: You also have to load the image to memory so that does not solve the problem.

Comment: well the problem is that the app crashes on this command...Bitmap picture=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard...");

Comment: Well after working a lot i found out that the problem was not with code but the ram size of emulator, editing avd and increasing ram size solves all problems and saves huges pics easily. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html explains how to load large images into a Bitmap without encountering the dreaded OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 1):

The Android VM has memory limitation which limits the size of the images decodable. To display the resixed images in an image view the following code could be used.

```
decode_options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(temp,decode_options);  //This will just fill the output parameters
if(decode_options.outWidth > image_width
        || decode_options.outHeight > image_height)
{
    float scale_width,scale_height;

    scale_width = ((float)decode_options.outWidth) / image_width;
    scale_param = scale_width;
    scale_height = ((float)decode_options.outHeight) / image_height;

    if(scale_param < scale_height)
        scale_param = scale_height;
}

decode_options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
decode_options.inSampleSize  = (int)(scale_param + 1);
decode_options.inPreferredConfig =  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
decoded_data = 
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(temp,decode_options);
```