# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Even in a try-catch block?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

**My application crashes, showing this in logcat:**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=39047KB, Allocated=19932KB)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeFile(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:373)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:443)
        at com.mApp.mobileapp.mActivity.onActivityResult(mActivity.java:196)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:153)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4752)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3503)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1320)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5109)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:991)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**While running this code:**

```
String selectedImagePath = data.getStringExtra("imageByteCode");
try {
    File imageFile = new File(selectedImagePath);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile
        .getAbsolutePath());//line 196
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    base64code = selectedImagePath;
    mImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Since i was catching it, i never expected it to crash the app. `selectedImagePath` is the path of the selected image on the SD card, which never exceeds **3m.b** but **Heap Size=39047KB, Allocated=19932KB** ??

Thank You

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You did not catch it. `OutOfMemoryError` is derived from `Error`, not from `Exception`. It is an `Error` because normally an application is not supposed to catch it, there is close to nothing your application can do to recover.

Comment: great. But none of the images are more than 3mb in size so, i might not be handling bitmap memory allocation the right way?

Comment: For loading large images this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798756/load-large-images-into-bitmap

Answer (score 10):

Place `android:largeHeap="true"` in your Manifest file under the **application** tag.

The **largeHeap** tells the VM to give you more RAM so you can manage big bitmaps and Strings.
**LargeHeap** works in api 12+.

And if you want to catch the error with try/catch block you need to use

```
try
        {

        }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

If you are experiencing this while building the project in Android Studio

```
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

add in your **build.gradle** file

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: Epic Answer. A lot of information in as few words as possible.
+1 largeheap.
+1 OutOfMemoryError can be recovered from (sometimes) and this is the code to do it. In this situation the asker was trying to open an image. Using `try catch(OutOfMemoryError)` this won't crash the app and an error message can be displayed to the user.

Comment: @Andy I am glad that I helped.

Comment: I still need to use a better image caching library, but this gives me some leeway! thanks (going from loopj to Universal Image Loader)

Comment: `android:largeHeap="true"` is usually a bad idea, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30930239/11278124